# Trying to Rip Single Title with 9 chapters on owned DVD using vobcopy

Tags: dvd

I am trying to rip a single title with 9 chapters using vobcopy. I have made an image of the DVD and can get it to read and play just fine however when I go to rip the title it rips some of the next title.

```
vobcopy /home/aadrik/Dr. \Who/DOCTOR_WHO_S8_DISC2.iso -n 3
```

What is making me frustrated is that it shows the length of the video as 5 minutes but it is actually more like 50ish, which is the length of the episode I want plus the beginning of the next. I dont understand why it is running over into the other. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile trying the same with `tccat`:

```
tccat /home/aadrik/Dr. \Who/DOCTOR_WHO_S8_DISC2.iso -d 2 -T 9,-1,1 > test.vob
```

`tccat` is a part of the `transcode` package:

```
sudo apt-get install transcode
```

It would be interesting to see if `tccat` can make a cleaner extraction...